# Listing protocol and content type handlers

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

Is there an XPCOM interface for listing all protocol handlers and content type handlers?

I see the information is available in mimeTypes.rdf, and although I see interfaces for getting info on a particular known handler, I couldn't find any XPCOM interface which lists all of them out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey Brett here's something I wrote while working on MailtoWebmails, please do share whatever you learn, quirks etc:

[GitHubGIST :: Noitidart / _ff-addon-tutorial-CheckGetSetRemoveAddHandlerOfProtocol.md](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/2faaac70c62bc13e7773)

### Get the `handlerInfo` object

`nsIHandlerService` Method

The `handlerInfo` object returned here is exactly same as doing it with the above method of `nsiExternalProtocolService`.

If you go to the options panel and change to alwaysAsk the `alwaysAskBeforeHandling` property in the log `handlerInfo`s will reflect properly.

```
var handlerService = Cc['@mozilla.org/uriloader/handler-service;1'].getService(Ci.nsIHandlerService);
var listOfWrappedHandlers = handlerService.enumerate();
var i = 0;
while (listOfWrappedHandlers.hasMoreElements()) {
  var handlerInfo = listOfWrappedHandlers.getNext().QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHandlerInfo);
  //console.log(i, 'handler for', wrappedHandlerInfo.type, wrappedHandlerInfo);
  if (handlerInfo.type == 'mailto') {
    break;
  }
  i++;
}
console.log('handlerServicehandlerInfo=', handlerInfo); //is the mailto one as we broke the loop once it found that
```

Does not have `possibleLocalHandlers` in `handlerInfo`.

`nsiExternalProtocolService` Method

The `handlerInfo` object returned here is exactly same as doing it with the above method of `nsIHandlerService`.

If you go to the options panel and change to alwaysAsk the `alwaysAskBeforeHandling` property in the log `handlerInfo`s will reflect properly.

```
var eps = Cc["@mozilla.org/uriloader/external-protocol-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIExternalProtocolService);
var handlerInfo = eps.getProtocolHandlerInfo('mailto');
console.log('epsHandlerInfo', handlerInfo)
```

Does not have `possibleLocalHandlers` in `handlerInfo`.

`nsIMIMEService` Method

note: has major quirks, like not accurately refelect `preferedHandler`and `alwaysAskBeforeHandling` (i just noticed these two so far I didnt explore other properties but they may be equally jacked up

Using the top two methods of `nsIHandlerService` and `nsiExternalProtocolService`, if you go to the options panel and change to alwaysAsk the `alwaysAskBeforeHandling` property in the log `handlerInfo`s will reflect properly. However if you get `handlerInfo` with this method, `nsIMIMEService`, then it doesnt accurately reflect the drop down setting from `alwaysAskBeforeHandling` its so weird:

It also has `possibleApplicationHandlers` which is length of `0`. Odd. It also has `possibleLocalHandlers` which has a length of `53` in my case, interesting.

```
var mimeService = Cc['@mozilla.org/mime;1'].getService(Ci.nsIMIMEService);
var CONTENT_TYPE = 'mailto';
var TYPE_EXTENSION = '';

var handlerInfo = mimeService.getFromTypeAndExtension(CONTENT_TYPE, TYPE_EXTENSION);
console.info('mimeServiceHandlerInfo:', handlerInfo); //http://i.imgur.com/dUKox24.png
```

This `mimeServiceHandlerInfo` also has different object keys from the `handlerInfo` returned by the top two methods of EPS and HandlerService.

### Check the handlers that are associated with this

Using `handlerInfo` from any of the three methods above (well I haven't yet tested `nsiMIMService`'s `handlerInfo` but I'm guessing it should work)

`queryElementAt` Method

This way does not list the "Microsoft Outlook", it only lists the gmail, ymail and things i added, weird

```
 var handlers = handlerInfo.possibleApplicationHandlers;
 console.log('handlers', handlers)
 for (var i = 0; i < handlers.length; ++i) {
   var handler = handlers.queryElementAt(i, Ci.nsIWebHandlerApp); //instead of Ci.nsIHandlerApp
   console.log('poss handler', i, handler, handler.uriTemplate);

 }
```

`enumerate` Method

I don't think this way lists the "Microsoft Outlook" either but I'm not sure as it's only logging small `handler` objects.

<s>This way only returns/logs small object (`handler`) for the first non system default handler (i think thats what it is, but it definitely only returns for one). for which it returns the name etc</s> I fixed this problem by adding in `.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHandlerApp)`

```
 var handlers = handlerInfo.possibleApplicationHandlers.enumerate();
 while (handlers.hasMoreElements()) {
   var handler = handlers.getNext().QueryInterface(Ci.nsIWebHandlerApp); //instead of Ci.nsIHandlerApp
   console.log('handler', handler);
 }
```

Notes on both `enumerate` and `queryElementAt`

- It was QI'ing `Ci.nsIHandlerApp` which would not have `uriTemplate` in the `handler` object, so I changed it to `Ci.nsIWebHandlerApp`, this retuns in hte object `uriTemplate`.

  - Can QI `handler`s in `possibleApplicationHandlers` with `Ci.nsIHandlerApp` BUT CANNOT QI `handler`s in `possibleLocalHandlers` with `Ci.nsIWebHandlerApp` it will throw the following exception:

    Exception: Component returned failure code: 0x80004002 (NS_NOINTERFACE) [nsISupports.QueryInterface]

### Add a handler to a protocol

`registerProtocolHandler` shows all the checks to make when adding a handler, and it shows how to add it. [MXR :: mozilla-release/ mozilla/ browser/ components/ feeds/ src/ WebContentConverter.js #L368 - registerProtocolHandler](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/browser/components/feeds/src/WebContentConverter.js#368)

This snippet shows how to add a `nsIWebAppHandler`. I'm not sure how to add a `nsILocalAppHandler` (im not sure if it's even called `nsILocalAppHandler` maybe its just (actually probably is) `nsIAppHandler`). No validation checks are made before adding it here. You should do the following checks before adding:

1. Check if the handler we're adding already exists as possible handler [MXR :: mozilla-release/ mozilla/ browser/ components/ feeds/ src/ WebContentConverter.js #349 - _protocolHandlerRegistered](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/browser/components/feeds/src/WebContentConverter.js#349)

   - Curious note here: This only checks `possibleApplicationHandlers` it doesn't do `possibleLocalHandlers`, i'm not sure why, but probably because we are dealing with a `nsIWebAppHandler`
2. Check to make sure the protocol we are adding handler to isn't already handled internally (we don't want to let them take over, say "chrome"). [MXR :: mozilla-release/ mozilla/ browser/ components/ feeds/ src/ WebContentConverter.js #390](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/browser/components/feeds/src/WebContentConverter.js#390)
3. Check if the protocol we are adding handler to is in the black list. If it's in the blacklist it means it does not want other handlers added to it. I'm not sure how important this is but `registerProtocolHandler` does it. [MXR :: mozilla-release/ mozilla/ browser/ components/ feeds/ src/ WebContentConverter.js #402](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/browser/components/feeds/src/WebContentConverter.js#402)

So finally here is the code on how to add a handler without doing any of the three checks above.

```
var protocol = 'mailto';
var name = 'Hotmail Mailto Handler';
var newURIArgs = {
    aURL: 'http://mail.live.com/secure/start?action=compose&to=%s',
    aOriginCharset: null,
    aBaseURI: null
};
var myURI = Services.io.newURI(newURIArgs.aURL, newURIArgs.aOriginCharset, newURIArgs.aBaseURI);
var myURISpec = myURI.spec;


var handler = Cc["@mozilla.org/uriloader/web-handler-app;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIWebHandlerApp);
handler.name = name;
handler.uriTemplate = myURISpec;

var eps = Cc["@mozilla.org/uriloader/external-protocol-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIExternalProtocolService);
var handlerInfo = eps.getProtocolHandlerInfo(protocol);
handlerInfo.possibleApplicationHandlers.appendElement(handler, false);

if (handlerInfo.possibleApplicationHandlers.length > 1) {
    // May want to always ask user before handling because it now has multiple possibleApplicationsHandlers BUT dont have to
    //handlerInfo.alwaysAskBeforeHandling = true;
}

var hs = Cc["@mozilla.org/uriloader/handler-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIHandlerService);
hs.store(handlerInfo);
```

### How to get the currently set handler for a protocol

First get the `handlerInfo` object for the protocol by using Get the `handlerInfo` object - `nsIHandlerService` - Method or Get the `handlerInfo` object - `nsiExternalProtocolService` Method.

1. Then first check if `handlerInfo.alwaysAskBeforeHandling` is `true`. If this is the case than the active handler is "Always Ask". If this is the case than `handlerInfo.preferredApplicationHandler` and `handlerInfo.preferredAction` are stale. By stale I mean that they are not true, they are set to whatever it was set at before.
2. `handlerInfo.alwaysAskBeforeHandling` is `false` then check `handlerInfo.preferredAction`.

   - If `handlerInfo.preferredAction == Ci.nsIHandlerInfo.useSystemDefault` than the `handler.preferredApplicaitonHandler` is stale in that it is whatever it was set to last time. So the active handler is whatever the `userSystemDefault` one is. (at the time of this writing August 3rd, 2014 - I'm not sure how to figure out the system default handler for a protocol)
   - If `handlerInfo.preferredAction == Ci.nsIHandlerInfo.useHelperApp` than default handler is whatever is held in `handlerInfo.preferredApplicationHandler`. In this case `handler.preferredApplicaitonHandler` should not be `null`. In all other cases `handler.preferredApplicaitonHandler` has the potential to be `null`.
   - If `handlerInfo.preferredAction == Ci.nsIHandlerInfo.saveToDisk` than default handler is to download it
   - If `handlerInfo.preferredAction == Ci.nsIHandlerInfo.handleInternally` than default handler is I don't know as of writing of this (August 3rd, 2014)

### Demo/Example - Set the mailto handler to be "Yahoo! Mail"

```
//start - demo make handler for mailto be y! mail
var eps = Cc["@mozilla.org/uriloader/external-protocol-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIExternalProtocolService);
var handlerInfo = eps.getProtocolHandlerInfo('mailto');
console.log('epsHandlerInfo', handlerInfo)

var handlers = handlerInfo.possibleApplicationHandlers.enumerate();
var foundYahooMailHandler = false;
while (handlers.hasMoreElements()) {
    var handler = handlers.getNext();
    if (handler.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIWebHandlerApp).uriTemplate == 'https://compose.mail.yahoo.com/?To=%s') { //this is how i decided to indentify if the handler is of yahoo mail
        foundYahooMailHandler = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (foundYahooMailHandler) {
    //it was found. and in the while loop when i found it, i "break"ed out of the loop which left handlerInfo set at the yahoo mail handler
    //set this to the prefered handler as this handler is the y! mail handler
    handlerInfo.preferredAction = Ci.nsIHandlerInfo.useHelperApp; //Ci.nsIHandlerInfo has keys: alwaysAsk:1, handleInternally:3, saveToDisk:0, useHelperApp:2, useSystemDefault:4
    handlerInfo.preferredApplicationHandler = handler;
    handlerInfo.alwaysAskBeforeHandling = false;
    var hs = Cc["@mozilla.org/uriloader/handler-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIHandlerService);
    hs.store(handlerInfo);
} else {
    alert('could not find yahoo mail handler. meaning i couldnt find a handler with uriTemplate of ...compose.mail.yahoo....')
}
//end - demo make handler for mailto be y! mail
```

### Demo/Example of how to remove handler

```
var eps = Cc["@mozilla.org/uriloader/external-protocol-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIExternalProtocolService);
var handlerInfo = eps.getProtocolHandlerInfo('mailto');
console.log('epsHandlerInfo', handlerInfo)

console.log('handlerInfo.preferredApplicationHandler', handlerInfo.preferredApplicationHandler);
console.log('handlerInfo.possibleApplicationHandlers', handlerInfo.possibleApplicationHandlers);

var handlers = handlerInfo.possibleApplicationHandlers;
console.log('handlers', handlers)
for (var i = 0; i < handlers.length; ++i) {
    var handler = handlers.queryElementAt(i, Ci.nsIWebHandlerApp);
    console.log('handler', i, handler, handler.uriTemplate);

    if (Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow(null).confirm('delete handler at position ' + i + '? its uriTemplate = "' + handler.uriTemplate + '" and name = "' + handler.name + '"')) {
        if (handler.equals(handlerInfo.preferredApplicationHandler)) {
            Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow(null).alert('the preferredApplicationHandler was the one we are removing now, so null the preferredAppHand and set to always ask');
            //if the last preferredApplicationHandler was this then nullify it, just me trying to keep things not stale
            handlerInfo.preferredApplicationHandler = null;
            if (handlerInfo.preferredAction == Ci.nsIHandlerInfo.useHelperApp) {
                //it looks like the preferredAction was to use this helper app, so now that its no longer there we will have to ask what the user wants to do next time the uesrs clicks a mailto: link
                handlerInfo.alwaysAskBeforeHandling = true;
                handlerInfo.preferredAction = Ci.nsIHandlerInfo.alwaysAsk; //this doesnt really do anything but its just nice to be not stale. it doesnt do anything because firefox checks handlerInfo.alwaysAskBeforeHandling to decide if it should ask. so me doing this is just formality to be looking nice
            }
        }
        handlers.removeElementAt(i);
        i--;
    }
    var hs = Cc["@mozilla.org/uriloader/handler-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIHandlerService);
    hs.store(handlerInfo);
}
```

Comment: Wow. I think I should add [Noitidart] as a synonym for the Firefox add-ons tag. :)

Comment: hahahah :P @BrettZamir formatting on stackoverflow is messed up, formatting at the gist is a bit better